# Python regex match square bracket issue

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a datatime inside square brackets and I thought prefixing "\" would be the way to encode square brackets but somehow it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import re

line_nginx = re.compile(r"""\[(?P<time_local>\S+) -700\]""", re.IGNORECASE) 

match = line_nginx.match("[07/Oct/2014:19:43:08 -0700]")
if match:
    print("matched")
else:
    print("no match")
```

I got "no match". Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[(?P<time_local>\S+)\s+-0700\]
```

Try this.You have `0700` instead of `700`.Also add `\s+`instead of space in your regex to make it less fragile.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/5

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to,

```
\[(?P<time_local>\S+) -0700\]
```

OR

```
\[(?P<time_local>\S+)\s+-0700\]
```

It's not the problem with escaping the starting or closing square bracket . You failed to add `0` before the number `7`, so your regex wouldn't match the input string.

```
>>> import re
>>> line_nginx = re.compile(r"\[(?P<time_local>\S+)\s+-0700\]", re.IGNORECASE)
>>> match = line_nginx.match("[07/Oct/2014:19:43:08 -0700]")
>>> if match:
...     print("matched")
... else:
...     print("no match")
... 
matched
```